# notification doesn't show up on selected time

Tags: java, android, kotlin, push-notification

I have a time picker in my app, a createNoificationChannel function, and a sendNotifications function. Everything is working but when I press the button the notification works after seconds from pressing the button not in the selected time by the time picker!!. I don't know how to link the time picker with the sendNotifications function. any help would be appreciated.

**Kotlin or java only..**

**my setting activity**

```
 private val CHNNEL_ID = "adthan_channel_id"
private val notificationId = 101

private lateinit var picker : MaterialTimePicker
private lateinit var calender : Calendar
private lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager
private lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent
```

**my notification buttons**

```
//صلاة الفجر


      fajrSalah.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->

            if (isChecked){
                showTimePicker()

                editor.putBoolean("fajrSalahChecked", isChecked)
                editor.apply()

            }else{
                editor.remove("fajrSalahChecked")
                editor.apply()

              //  cancelAlarm()
                toast("تم حذف المنبة")
            }
        }
        zuherSalah.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked){
                showTimePicker()

                editor.putBoolean("zuherSalahChecked", isChecked)
                editor.apply()

            }else{
                editor.remove("zuherSalahChecked")
                editor.apply()

             //   cancelAlarm()
                toast("تم حذف المنبة")
            }
   

 }
    adhanNotifcationBtn.setOnClickListener {

        sendNotifications("موعد صلاة العصر","بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم")

 }
```

**my notification functions**

```
private fun showTimePicker(){

    picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
        .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
        .setHour(12)
        .setMinute(0)
        .setTitleText("حدد الموعد الذي تريدة")
        .build()

    picker.show(supportFragmentManager, "AdhanNotifacations")

    picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {

        calender = Calendar.getInstance()
        calender[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = picker.hour
        calender[Calendar.MINUTE] = picker.minute
        calender[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
        calender[Calendar.MILLISECOND] = 0


    }
}
  private fun createNoificationChannel(){

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

        val name : CharSequence = " أشعارات الصلاوات"
        val descriptionText = "منبة لأشعارات الصلاوات"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHNNEL_ID,name,importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }
        val notificationManager : NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
      //  val notificationManager :NotificationManager = getSystemService( NotificationManager::class.java)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

}
private fun sendNotifications( title : String, content: String){

    alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager



    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
       flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    }
     pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(

        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calender.timeInMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent
    )

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHNNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_fajr_icon)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(content)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)){
        notify(notificationId, builder.build())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using **DatePickerDialog** and **TimePickerDialog**, use the `setOnClickListener` to retrieve values and store it somewhere (either via variables or `SharedPreferences`). Then, construct the *content* with these values and pass it in as the second argument for `sendNotification()`.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with a sample of your answer or if you could share a link showing what you are saying.. thank u

Comment: So if it solved my issue I can mark it as solved

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker) should give you a good idea of how to do it but if you want a complete tutorial then perhaps [this](https://www.journaldev.com/9976/android-date-time-picker-dialog) may help you. And sure if it answered your question (and solved your issue), then you can do that.